# Steps to consume an axis webservice in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, web-services, axis

I am trying real hard to consume a web service in Visual Studio 2008. Can anybody tell me how do I go about doing it? Or is there a link that will give me the exhaustive steps to consume an axis webservice in Visual Studio 2008?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Consume Axis2 Web Services in Visual Studio 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/968957/consume-axis2-web-services-in-visual-studio-2008)

Answer (score 0):

A similar thread here

[Consume Axis2 Web Services in Visual Studio 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968957/consume-axis2-web-services-in-visual-studio-2008)

Another reference :

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/Java_WS_NET.aspx